# JDBC connections failing only in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, ioerror

This is weird: any JDBC connection from any webapp deployed in Tomcat fails with

```
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

while they work perfectly fine from the command line or from Jetty.

Tomcat is running on Photon OS (a Linux variant from VMware) with Oracle JDK.
I tried

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

to no avail.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? I've never seen that kind of error before...

Comment: I found that if I put the db server hostname in the /etc/hosts file the webapps are working.
It's quite strange since the nslookup command resolves the hostname just fine...

Comment: It's possible that Java isn't using the same resolver as `nslookup` though that would be a little weird. Maybe Tomcat is running as a user who can't read `/etc/resolv.conf` or something like that?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz That was it! 
Tomcat is running as the tomcat user.
/etc/resolv.conf permissions were 640 (root:root); I changed them to 644 and lo'! Everything is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ChristopherSchultz, the problem were the incorrect permissions of the /etc/resolv.conf file (640 instead of 644).

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` should always be world-readable. Otherwise, nobody can perform DNS lookups!